# Converting JSON to CSV, CSV is empty

Tags: python

I'm attempting to convert yelps data set that is in JSON to a csv format. The new csv file that is created is empty.

I've tried different ways to iterate through the JSON but they all give me a zero bytes file.

The json file looks like this:

```
{"business_id":"1SWheh84yJXfytovILXOAQ","name":"Arizona Biltmore Golf Club","address":"2818 E Camino Acequia Drive","city":"Phoenix","state":"AZ","postal_code":"85016","latitude":33.5221425,"longitude":-112.0184807,"stars":3.0,"review_count":5,"is_open":0,"attributes":{"GoodForKids":"False"},"categories":"Golf, Active Life","hours":null}
```

```
import json 
import csv

infile = open("business.json","r")
outfile = open("business2.csv","w")

data = json.load(infile)
infile.close()

out = csv.writer(outfile)

out.writerow(data[0].keys())
for row in data:
    out.writerow(row.values())
```

I get an "extra data" message when the code runs. The new business2 csv file is empty and the size is zero bytes.

Comment: You never close the file you're writing to. The write buffer won't get flushed to the file and it probably locks the file (on Windows at least)

Comment: just add outfile.close() in the end to close the file and check.

Answer (score 0):

if you JSON has only one row.. then try this

```
infile = open("business.json","r")
outfile = open("business2.csv","w")

data = json.load(infile)
infile.close()

out = csv.writer(outfile)

#print(data.keys())
out.writerow(data.keys())
out.writerow(data.values())
```

Comment: .. still doesn't close the file, which is the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try the below code, by using `with` command the file access will automatically get closed when the control moves out of scope of `with`

```
infile = open("business.json","r")
outfile = open("business2.csv","w")

data = json.load(infile)
infile.close()
headers = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())

with open("business2.csv","w") as outfile:
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
    out.writerow(headers)
    out.writerow(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `with` to close file.

```
import json 
import csv

infile = open("business.json","r")


data = json.load(infile)
infile.close()

with open("business2.csv","w") as outfile:
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
    out.writerow(list(data.keys()))
    out.writerow(list(data.values()))
```